# VI editor ctrl+] warning when multiple tags exits

Tags: vim, vi

I want vi editor to throw warning message if multiple tags exits when i search for tag using ctl+]. If it's only one tag, it should jump to the tag position.

How can we do achieve this?

Regards,
Venkat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>ctrl + ]</kbd>.

If you prefer <kbd>ctrl + ]</kbd> you can just remap it:

```
:nnoremap <c-]> g<c-]>
```

Comment: Excellent-Thanks. it is working. Can it show the filenames also along with tags which will be more useful to select which tag to choose.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. File names are shown in my vim and I think that is the normal behaviour. (What I see is what is depicted in `:help tselect`)